# Write Data from Multiple Site to JSON File BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape multiple websites that have the same HTML structure and write the content to a JSON file.  The results for each URL print out in the terminal, but only the content from the last URL listed is written into the JSON file.  I have not been able to figure out a solution.  Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

urls = ['https://scholarworks.gvsu.edu/books/', 'https://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/pdxopen/', 'https://oer.galileo.usg.edu/all-textbooks/index.html', 'https://oer.galileo.usg.edu/all-textbooks/index.2.html', 'https://digitalcommons.trinity.edu/textbooks/']

#scrape elements
for url in urls:
    uClient = urlopen(url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"content_block"})
    source = page_soup.find("div",{"id":"series-header"})

    data = []
        for container in containers:
        item = {}
        item['type'] = "Textbook"
        item['title'] = container.h2.text
        item['author'] = container.p.text
        item['link'] = container.a["href"]
        item['source'] = source.h2.text
        data.append(item) # add the item to the list
        print(container.h2.text)

with open("./json/multiple.json", "w") as writeJSON:
   json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Your code is misformatted; I think your inner loop needs to be unindented four spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-initializing `data` with each URL. I think you want to put the initialization above your outer loop:

```
data = []
#scrape elements
for url in urls:
    # Etc.
```